# How to copy file based on date in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a list of files in a adls container which contain date in the name as given below:

```
TestFile-Name-20221120. csv
TestFile-Name-20221119. csv
TestFile-Name-20221118. csv
```

and i want to copy files which contain today date only like TestFile-Name-20221120. csv on today and so on.
I've used get metedata activity to get list of files and then for each to iterate over each file and then used set variable to extract name from the file like 20221120 but not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

We have something similar running. We check an SFTP folder for the existanc e of files, using the `Get Metadata` activity. In our case, there can be folders or files. We only want to process files, and very specific ones for that matter (I.e. we have 1 pipeline per filename we can process, as the different filenames would contain different columns/datatypes etc).

Our pipeline looks like this:

[image]

Within our `Get Metadata` component, we basically just filter for the name of the object we want, and we only want files ending in .zip, meaning we added a Filename filter:

[image]:

In your case, the first part would be 'TestFile-Name-', and the second part would be *.csv'.

We then have a `For Each` loop set up, to process anything (the child items) we retrieved in the `Get Metadata` step. Within the `For Each` we defined an `If Condition` to only process files, and not folders.

In our cases, we use the following expression:

```
@equals(item().type, 'File')
```

In your case, you could use something like:

```
@endsWith(item().name, concat(<variable containing your date>, '.csv'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the file names start with TestFile-Name-,
and you want to copy the data of file with todays date,
use get metadata activity to check if the file exists and the file name can be dynamic like

@concat('TestFile-Name-',utcnow(),'.csv')

Note: you need to fromat utcnow as per the needed format

and if file exists, then proceed for copy else ignore